# javascript underscore - invoke

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using underscore.js how do I alert each item in the array? Is this even possible? I tried using the invoke function but its not working. can you please help?

```
_.invoke([1,3,7],alert(this));
```

Comment: try `function(){alert(this)}` for the second argument

Comment: Okay, so, this is actually **directly** covered [in the documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#each), which gives this example for the `each` function: `_.each([1, 2, 3], alert);`

Comment: @JanDvorak Btw, `this` will refer to `window` object in your example.

Comment: @dfsq  you're right. `this` is how it works in jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[invoke](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) is not right method for this task. Try [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) instead:

```
_.each([1,3,7], alert);
```

Or you can call `alert` explicitly:

```
_.each([1,3,7], function(el) {
    alert(el);
});
```

Comment: Just be sure to test on your target browsers. The host-provided functions like `alert` can be ... dodgy on some older browsers when you use them indirectly like that. But also note that `_.each([1, 2, 3], alert);` is *the example in the documentation*, so...